# for loop error calculating prime numbers C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm attempting to learn how to code and I am struggling as I try to learn what is wrong with my code. I'm programming using Visual studio 2013 in C++.

Question: Write a program to read a number N from the user and then ﬁnd the ﬁrst N primes. A prime number is a number that only has two divisors, one and itself.

Instead of my code printing out a sequence of prime numbers, it repeats some of the prime numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// this program will calculate the first N primes


int main(){

    int N;
    cin >> N;

    for (int i = 2; i < N; i++){
        for (int j = 2; j < N; j++){

            if (i%j == 0){
                break;

            }
            else
                cout << i << " " << "is a prime number\n";
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a programming problem, it is a mathematical problem i.e. your mistake isn't in your code, it's in your lack of understanding of how to determine if a number is prime. Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) for ideas. You've also misread the problem - it wants you to find the first N primes e.g. if N = 3, then you have to find the first 3 prime numbers which are 2, 3, and 5. You appear to be searching for primes between 2 and N-1 instead.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever `j` doesn't divide `i`, you're printing out that `i` is prime. You should wait until you've checked *all* the possible divisors. I'm not going to give you the answer of what you should do, but it should involve modifying this section of your code:

```
if (i%j == 0){
break;

}
else
cout << i << " " << "is a prime number\n";
}
```

Comment: That's just part of the problem. He's also failing to search for the first N primes (instead only searching for primes between 2 and N-1).

Answer (score 0):

**Mistakes in your code:**

1. You have to check all possible values before saying its prime. So you need to use a flag to determine if any values divided ***i*** in your loop.
2. You have to continue the second loop till `i` and not `N`

**Optimization**

1. Its only required to check till `sqrt(Number)` to check if its prime and not till Number -1.

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;
   // this program will calculate the first N primes


   int main(){

       int N;
       cin >> N;

       for (int i = 2; i < N; i++){
           int f=0;
           for (int j = 2; j*j <= (i); j++){

               if (i%j == 0){
                   f=1;
                   break;

               }

           }
           if(!f) Cout<<i<<"is prime"<<endl;       
       }
   }
   ```